Question on Friedmans distinction between the set and predicate versions of Russell Paradox via extensionality differences
In Friedmans paper : [1] he draws a distinction (page 2) between the set and predicate versions of Russells paradox, based upon the different treatments of extensionality :
Friedmans Extensionality for Sets is defined as :
$$ \forall z ( z \in x \iff z \in y) \implies \forall z (x \in z \iff y \in z)\tag{1} $$
Friedman then says that a similar treatment of Extensionality for Predicates, does NOT seem appropriate :
$$ \forall R (P(R) \iff Q(R)) \implies \forall R (R(P) \iff R(Q)) \tag{2}   $$
because "For instance, one may distinguish different predicates P, Q such that P, Q fail at every argument, where P, Q can be distinguished by another predicate R. Then we have $ \forall R (P(R) \iff Q(R)) $ and yet $ \neg \forall R (R(P) \iff R(Q)) $.
In addition Friedman adopts the convention that "$x \in y$" notation is used even if x, y are predicates and we are asserting that y holds at x.
Questions:
Equation (1) : If two sets have the same elements but have different names, then the RHS of (1) would not necessarily apply, so why is this definition adopted ?
Equation (2) : Is there an example illustrating Friedmans "because ..." in particular to explain what "P, Q can be distinguished by another predicate R" means ?
[1] https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2014/01/FromRusselltoSetThy-1rnmfbg.pdf

The idea of extensionality is that sets, by their nature, are completely determined by their elements. Two sets are the same if and only if their elements are the same, full stop. This is what the axiom of extensionality says.
I'm not sure what you mean by two sets having different names... what is the name of a set? Ok, though. Let's say we have a set named "Kramer" and a set named "Cosmo". I assume you mean to let $z$ be "the set of all sets named 'Kramer'" or something like that which would include one but not the other.
But how do we know that a set can't be named both "Cosmo" and "Kramer"? You would have to show that names uniquely specify a set... but since sets are uniquely specified by their elements, you'd need to show that the name of a set is uniquely specified by its elements... so the situation you're proposing can't happen.
Or if names aren't unique, then maybe we have the set $\{n\in \mathbb N: \mbox{$n$ is odd and $n^{26}$ is even }\}$ called "Cosmo" and the set $\{r\in \mathbb R: r^2+1 =0\}$ called "Kramer". But then we do a little thinking and figure out that there aren't any elements in either set, so they have the same elements, so by extensionality they're the same. So there's only one set here and it has the name "Cosmo", it has the name "Kramer", and it has the name "the empty set".
On the other hand, the idea of a predicate is different from the idea of a set. A predicate is some property that may or may not be satisfied by some object, where as the corresponding set is just the things that have the property, Consider the predicates "is an odd natural number whose twenty-sixth power is even" and "is a real number whose square plus one is zero". Now, these are very different concepts superficially about different kinds of objects, that we just happen to know are co-extensive. It makes sense that there could be something distinguishing the predicates, even if the corresponding sets are the same, and thus the axiom of extensionality seems inappropriate for predicates.
But formal theories of predicates are not familiar to me like formal theories of sets (and I haven't read the paper if there's anything elucidating in there), so I don't know what kinds of things are taken as invariant properties of predicates, and so don't know precisely what kind of the counterexample "R" might say here.

I was wondering whether Friedman is alluding to the identity of indiscernibles in (2) [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles#Indiscernibility_of_identicals] in the section titled "Identity and indiscernibility" ? To get reflexivity needs the identity of indiscernibles ?

@Confusdius identity of indiscernibles (and its converse) motivates defining equality $P=Q$ as the RHS of 2 and hence having that be statement of extensionality. (And since singleton sets exist, set membership is a fine enough collection of properties to distinguish unequal objects and the RHS of 1 works to define set equality $x=y$ as well.)
